Type error initializing sequelize model with virtual datatype
I'm trying to define a model in sequelize that uses a virtual datatype, but I'm getting a type error. This is my model definition:
export const Contact = sequelize.define("contact", {
  firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
  lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
  fullName: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get(){ return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`.trim()},
    set() {throw "Set firstName, lastName instead!"}
  }
})

However, the getter on the fullName field has a type error on the firstName and lastName properties. Both read Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'.
Can the DataTypes.VIRTUAL type be used in a type safe way? Should I just implement this a plain property on the model object?
